# tabu+makecell+xcolor = Improper \prevdepth

Tags: errors, color, tabu, compilation-error, makecell

The packages tabu, makecell and xcolor seems to interact in incompatible ways:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{l|X@{}}
    hi & \makecell[tl]{hi \\ by}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

**LOG**

> Improper \prevdepth. \end{tabu}

But if you comment out `\usepackage{xcolor}` (or don't use `makecell` in the tabu environment), it will compile without errors

I have MikTex 2.9 on Windows

Comment: The package `tabu` is buggy and code like your doesn't work in it. Try to use `tabularx` instead of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with `tabularx` because it cannot handle `X` columns with a coefficient. @raffamaiden Thanks for reporting here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|l|X@{}|}
  \hline
    hi & \SetCell{t,l,cyan9}{hi \\ by} \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lX}[hvlines]
  hi & \Block[t,l,fill=cyan!15]{}{hi \\ by} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]